# How to call template from another template in XSLT?

Tags: xml, templates, xslt

I have the following xml:

```
<rootelement>
   <parentelement>
      <mytype>123</mytype>
      <myvalue>abc</myvalue>
   </parentelement>
   <parentelement>
      <mytype>234</mytype>
      <myvalue>xyz</myvalue>
   </parentelement>
</rootelement>
```

First I apply template that uses dictionary to change values of mytype:

```
   <parentelement>
      <mytype>Mapped1</mytype>
      <myvalue>abc</myvalue>
   </parentelement>
   <parentelement>
      <myvalue>qwe</myvalue>
   </parentelement>
```

I want to apply next transform that removes the whole parentelement if mytype tag was removed. In other words I want the second transform to create the following XML:

```
   <parentelement>
      <mytype>Mapped1</mytype>
      <myvalue>abc</myvalue>
   </parentelement>
```

I've tried adding at the end of the first template the following:

```
<xsl:template match="mytype">
    ...
    <xsl:call-template name="mytypetemplate"/>
</xsl:template>
```

With the following template as the second one:

```
<xsl:template name="mytypetemplate" match="/rootelement/parentelement[not(mytype) or mytype[not(node())]]"/>
```

But the result I got is that it executes the first template, but not the second one. In other words, it removes mytype (first template) but it does not remove the whole parentelement for element without mytype (second template). How can I apply the second transform after the first one?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you running the two transformations separately? Or do you want to write one stylesheet that performs two transformation steps, where the second step transforms the output from the first step? Which XSLT processor, which XSLT version do you use?

Comment: I use XSLT version 3.0. I'm not sure about processor version but I think it's built in Java. These templates are in the same XSLT file, they are two separate templates. I want to execute first and then the second one (on the results from the first one), whichever way is simpler (separately or in one template). I suspect that it's easier if they are separate templates but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can separate processing steps using `mode`s (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#element-mode) and use variables to store and use temporary results, in the example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
    <xsl:mode name="step1" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:variable name="step1-result">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="step1"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="parentelement[myvalue = 'abc']/mytype" mode="step1"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$step1-result/node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="parentelement[not(mytype)]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the mode `step1` removes the `mytype` element from `parentelement`s with `myvalue` being `abc` and the default mode processes the temporary result created in the variable `step1-result` to eliminate any `parentelement`s not having a `mytype` child.

So for the input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rootelement>
    <parentelement>
        <mytype>123</mytype>
        <myvalue>abc</myvalue>
    </parentelement>
    <parentelement>
        <mytype>234</mytype>
        <myvalue>xyz</myvalue>
    </parentelement>
</rootelement>
```

then result is

```
<rootelement>

        <parentelement>
                <mytype>234</mytype>
                <myvalue>xyz</myvalue>
        </parentelement>
</rootelement>
```

Online at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/b4GWV2.

A slight variant is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  <xsl:mode name="step1" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="parentelement[myvalue = 'abc']/mytype" mode="step1"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="step1-result">
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="step1"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$step1-result/node()"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="parentelement[not(mytype)]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

you can see that online at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/b4GWV2/1.

Comment: Thank you! However, when I paste XML and XSL to https://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html, I receive error. The other site (http://www.utilities-online.info/xsltransformation) shows empty result. Is there any online tool were I can check it?

Comment: I have put an XSLT 2 version (where the `xsl:mode` have been spelled out by the identity transformation) at http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/3Nqn5Ya. In general to run XSLT 3 you need Saxon 9.8 as available on Sourceforge or Maven or NuGet or in the commercial editions from Saxonica.

Comment: Can you, please, explain a bit more how it works? I've tried applying it to my original problem and what I got is concatenation of all the strings that are in my tags, witout tags (I have tried both variations). Especially, I'm not sure why you use match="/" and why the last one template does not include mode attribute. I assume that template with mode equal to step1 is not executed immediately but rather as assignment to the variable. Then there is apply-templates which I'm not sure how it works, but I guess it calls the last template. I'm about to read more about modes.

Comment: If you want to learn XSLT then https://cranesoftwrights.github.io/books/ptux/index.htm has a free download of an introduction to XSLT 1 and 2, I am sure it teaches you all you need to know about `xsl:apply-templates` and `xsl:mode`.

Comment: As for the XSLT 3 version, the default mode has no name and so `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` is the default processing set up for that unnamed default mode and of course `<xsl:template match="parentelement[not(mytype)]"/>` then overrides the default mode's processing for those `parentelement`s, so that is why it has no mode attribute, it belongs to the unnamed default mode.